# Custom item in context menu when I right-click on folder

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, user-folders

Has this been asked before? I want a custom item in the context menu when I right click on a folder. I know you're supposed to do it through the registry, but I don't know how. I will manage what it executes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the registry, you go into `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, Folder, and then shell. Here you create a new key by right-clicking on shell and going to new then Key. Name it what ever you want. Then create a key inside that which is named command and set the default value to the action you want(for example a exe file). It's done!

Comment: Linking to your blog needlessly may be considered [self-promotion](/help/promotion). Please do so only when relevant